# UICollectionView setting first cell to always be specific content

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Hi so I'm using a side scrolling `UICollectionView` to display groups of people that the user makes. The groups are stored on my server and when the view loads, they load from the server. However I want the first cell to always be the same which is a cell which lets you create groups. This is the layout i need.

[image]

I know how to use multiple different custom cells, but how do I make it so the first cell is static and the cells after load content from my servers? Thanks :)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return familyName.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
    let cell : AddGroupCollectionViewCell = collectionViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Add", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddGroupCollectionViewCell

    return cell

    } else {

    let cell : FriendGroupsCell = collectionViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendGroupsCell


    cell.groupImage.image = UIImage(named: "pp")
    cell.groupNameLabel.text = familyName[indexPath.row]

    return cell
    }
}
```

This is my code and it misses out the first person in the array because the index path skips over it. How can i modify this so it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UICollectionViewCell is leveraging reusing techniques to improve performance. Remember this. Nothing can be static in a cell, because this cell later will be on another index.

You can use `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to make the first cell always load the same images/labels via `indexPath.row == 0`

You can use `prepareReuse` method to clean up the resources in the cell. So if cell No.2 is going to be the new No.1 cell, it get a chance to clean up old resources.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : AddGroupCollectionViewCell = collectionViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Add", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddGroupCollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.groupImage.image = UIImage(named: "new")
        cell.groupNameLabel.text = "new"
    } else {
        cell.groupImage.image = UIImage(named: "pp")
        cell.groupNameLabel.text = familyName[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: you don't have to use two cell identifiers, since there are no different for the first one and rest. They are just different appearance and event. Simply use one and customize them. Of course you can use two identifiers for your needs, but the point is you know how to do it... I think it's obvious now.

Comment: I see, ill use this. But even that still skips the first item in my array of familyName, because the first time its called it will be 0, and the second time it will be 1, this means that it will skip familyName[0] which i cant have? I could use a indexPath.row-1 but thats bad practice is it not?

Comment: There's no bad practice since you designed it. Simply unified them into one array or you just -1.

Comment: Okay i added +1 to my row count and -1 on my friends index path, works now! Thank you